# Getting strange behaviour converting a Seq to a String in my message handler

Tags: scala, akka

I am doing some logging in the receive for a particular message I receive and am getting some bizarre behaviour. My code goes something like this:

```
case class Message(id: Int, items: Seq[Item])

def receive = {
  case Message(id, items) =>
    log.debug(s"Message received[$id]: $items");
}
```

Occasionally I get the following exception in the line where I log:

> scala java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty stream

*Unfortunately I didn't manage to save the full stack trace and it is not something that happens regularly. But I can say it originates in immutable.Stream.toString which comes from the call to convert items to a string*

This despite the fact there are items in my Seq and I never intended for it to be a stream. The items originate in a Map and I create my message by doing something like the following:

```
val map: Map[Int, Item]
...
es.publish(Message(id, map.values.toSeq))
```

Why is the string conversion for the logging treating it like a stream?
And is there an issue with sending streams in akka messages?

Comment: What is `Item`? Is it some specific class?

Comment: what scala version are you using?

Comment: what is the implementation of `Map[Int, Item]`. do `println(map.getClass)` to see the real implementation used

Comment: Am using scala 2.12 and the Map class is initialised to: scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$

Answer (score -1):

`Map.values` returns an `Iterable` and the `toSeq` comes from `TraversableOnce`, which in turn calls `toStream` when you call `toSeq`.

This is a problem with the Seq abstraction or the Stream abstraction. However you want to look at it.
List and Stream both implement Seq, but have different behaviour for certain operations. Imagine having an infinite Stream and you call .tail on it. it would never return.

I tend to not use Seq anymore, but use List everywhere. And Stream explicitly where I want Stream behaviour.

Comment: So is it not allowed to pass a Stream in a message when using akka? Meaning I should always explicitly convert to a List?

Comment: `tail` on an infinite stream returns another infinite stream if the second value of the stream is known.